# Best practices for securing mobile apps that use web services

Tags: web-services, security, mobile, azure, titanium

I am developing apps using Appcelerator Titanium and they integrate with our web service which is hosted in Windows Azure. I need to know what are the most common attacks and what are some best practices to protect against them? I would need you to guide me to some good resources .

Thank you

Comment: Did I get you right here: Your questions; You want to secure your services running in Azure? Follow - up question: Where do these services run in Azure?

Comment: Next question is "which are the most common attacks against web services", right?

Comment: " Where do these services run in Azure? " - what do you mean? I haven' done any previous work on security so I'm trying to get a starting point. You are right, that is what I am asking. Thanks

Comment: I'll be meeting with a couple of Azure MVPs next Monday and I would be happy to bring up any security related issues. As of now I dont think there are any better sources than the ones I already provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Here is what I would call the best possible starting point for securing mobile services:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh696898.aspx

If you are running your are running web services in a web role you could also check this one out. 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/best-practices/security/

I've had good use of them both!

Comment: First link is now dead. Second link page is gone.